# Conditional check when summing in Mongodb aggregate

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregate

I'm trying to create a `viewAmount` attribute on a `Video` document where we sum up something it owns called `Views`, but only where `view.valid = true`.

This is what I have so far:

```
{
        $project: {
          title: 1,
          viewAmount: { $size: "$views" }
        }
      },
```

What can I add to do a conditional check if the view is valid or not rather than just noting the size? Do I have to use the `$unwind` operator? Thanks

Edit:

I am actually checking if view.validity (checkedView.validity) is equal to 'real'.

Here's my updated answer so far which isn't quite working:

```
{ $project: {
          title: 1,
          viewAmount: {
            $size: {
              $filter: {
                input: "$checkedViews",
                as: "view",
                cond: { $eq: ["$$view.validity", "real"] }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
```

An example Video:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59b5d09980348a3ec3541acc"),
    "checkedViews" : [ 
        ObjectId("59b5d0b280348a3ec3541acd"), 
        ObjectId("59b5d0bf80348a3ec3541ace"), 
        ObjectId("59b5d1dbd8f37d4ab797fa5c")
    ]
}
```

An example checkedView:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59b5d0b280348a3ec3541acd"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2017-09-10T23:54:26.752Z"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-09-10T23:54:26.752Z"),
    "video" : ObjectId("59b5d09980348a3ec3541acc"),
    "validity" : "real",
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Comment: Try `{
  "$project": {
    "$size": {
      "$filter": {
        "input": "$views",
        "as": "view",
        "cond": "$$view.valid"
      }
    }
  }
}`

Comment: added an edit @Veeram

Comment: Consider adding test data. It's hard to tell without the data  and without knowing problem you see when you run the query.

Comment: Okay updated. It looks like the conditional is working, if my conditional is:                `cond: { $eq: [1, 1] }`, I get the proper viewAmount, but if I do                 `cond: { $eq: ['$$view.validity', 'real'] }`, then I get 0 as the viewAmount @Veeram

Comment: ah I see. You have two separate collections. You need a lookup stage before filter. Something like 
    `{
        $lookup: {
            from: "checkedView",
            localField: "checkedViews",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "checkedViews"
        }
    }`

Comment: Cool, I think that will work (haven't tested but seems legit with what I've read about $lookup), can you add that as an answer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get looked up array count for a document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43821447/get-looked-up-array-count-for-a-document)

Comment: Can't get this one to work @Veeram: 
      `{ $lookup: { from: "views", localField: "checkedViews", foreignField: "_id", as: "populatedViews" } },`
(The collection is in the db as only 'views' not 'checkedViews')

Comment: This is working now: `      { $lookup: { from: "views", localField: "checkedViews.id", foreignField: "id", as: "checkedViews" } },`, but it's loading checkedViews from other uploads onto each uploads (ie they're not grouped by an _id). I thought $lookup would automatically group by ID but maybe I have to do it myself?

Comment: May be your not matching them correctly. Check  your foreignField variable.

Comment: I'm correctly matching them, but I'm getting all views documents from the database (898) and they're being attached to every video. I just want to attach them when the Id matches. I want to do a filter but I can't find a way to do something like                 `cond: { $eq: ['$$view.id', '$checkedViews.id'] }` <--- is there a syntax for this so I can filter and match by ID?